# Redux-form validation of several tabs

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have several tabs with redux-form fields. Of course, I have a validator, that have to validate just active tab. But there's a little problem. When I change active tab, validator checks fields value just if I try to do anything (click on any fields for example).
The question is *How can I pass formProps to validator when I change active tab?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A have a similar app working fine here.
I followed "Wizard Form" strategy (http://redux-form.com/6.3.1/examples/wizard/), using 1 form per tab, all using the same form name.
Make sure you render just the body/form of the active tab, and don't submit when changing tabs.

Comment: wha you posted is just half solution, what if person directly clicks on Eg:5th from 1st tab then, if there is validation error on 1st tab still he will be able to go to 5th tab